# Java app is crashing on nextLine()

Tags: java, crash, java.util.scanner

My application always crashs when it gets to `scan.getLine()` in `main`.
The error I get is "java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found".

Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = new String();
    int operation=0;
    operation = getOperation();
    System.out.print("Enter string:");
    s = scan.nextLine();  // program crashes before I have the chance to input anything
    System.out.println(s);
    scan.close();

}
public static int getOperation(){ //get operation between 1-10
    Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean input=true;
    int op=0;
    while (input){ // get correct input from the user
        if (scan.hasNextInt())
        {
            op=scan.nextInt();
            if (op < 1 || op > 10)
                System.out.print("Please enter valid operation 1-10:");
            else
                input=false;
        }
        else
            System.out.print("Please enter valid operation 1-10:");
        scan.nextLine(); // to clear the buffer
    }
    scan.close();
    return op;
}
```

The strange thing is that when I insert before I write `getOperation` function , and the entire `getOperation` was inside `main`, the application worked fine. Only after I moved the code to `getOperation` method , then the `scan.nextLine()` crashes, before I even have a change to enter anything in the console.

Comment: Try declaring 1 `Scanner` object (the one used in main) and pass it to the `getOperation` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this tiny code snippet

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner s1 = new Scanner(System.in);
   Scanner s2 = new Scanner(System.in);
   s2.close();
   s1.nextLine();
}
```

The close function closes the InputStream System.in

Since you are closing a scanner with `scan.close();` in `getOperation()` a following call on another scanner with the same InputStream will cause the exception that you are running into.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `Scanner` in main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = new String();
    System.out.print("Enter string:");
    int operation = 0;
    operation = getOperation();
    s = "" + operation; // program crashes before I have the chance to input anything
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

output:

```
Enter string:11
Please enter valid operation 1-10:1
1
```

Answer (score 0):

for me it was crashing when I used nextLine() after nextInt().
used parallel scanner (I am new to java):

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34163115)